# How to figure out which D-Bus binding to use

Tags: c, linux, x11, dbus

I'm trying to detect across all linux if screensaver is running or if screen is locked.

People recommended dbus. So now i'm trying to auto detect with x11 or C APIs or something what kind of dbus is available, then use that. Like qdubs, gdbus, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you’ve noticed, there are various D-Bus bindings available. As Ignacio says, you can use any of them, since they all speak the same protocol — but some bindings are more appropriate to some situations than others.

Recommended high-level bindings:

- [GDBus](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html) is a high level binding based around GLib/GObject. It’s appropriate to use if you’re writing a service or application based around GNOME technologies or GLib. It’s written in C, but bindings are available (at various levels of functionality) for other languages using gobject-introspection.
- [QtDBus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html) is a high level binding based around Qt. It’s appropriate to use if you’re writing a service or application based around Qt. It’s written in C++.

Recommended low-level bindings:

- [sd-bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-bus.html) is a lower level binding with very few dependencies. It’s appropriate if you’re writing a system service or system application and are not using GLib or Qt. It’s written in C.

*Not* recommended bindings:

- [libdbus](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/) is a lower level binding which comes with the official D-Bus implementation. It’s old, and the best practice in designing D-Bus APIs has improved since it was written. It is recommended you do *not* use libdbus. As the documentation says: “If you use this low-level API directly, you're signing up for some pain.”. It’s awkward to use. It’s written in C.
- [dbus-glib](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-glib/) is a high level binding which was affiliated with the official D-Bus implementation. Like libdbus, it’s old, and the best practice has moved on since then. It is recommended you do *not* use dbus-glib, and use GDBus instead. It’s awkward ot use. It’s written in C.

There are various [bindings for other languages available](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/), but I am not sure of their relative merits (if someone wants to edit this answer to cover those, that would be great).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. This is the detail that really connects the dots for me to Igancio's answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to detect what bindings for D-Bus are in use. Since they all speak the same way to the same thing, you only need to use *your* binding to talk to the message bus and interact with any other D-Bus client.

Comment: Thank you very much!! How to to know if i should do qdubs or gdubs though? See this guy here posted an issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/505681/unity-how-to-detect-if-the-screen-is-locked  he was using qdbus and then someone posted telling him to use gdbus which fixed  the problem

Comment: Yeah... no. They all speak the same way to the same thing. I don't know why it worked for him with one and not the other, but that's a red herring regardless.