# Proper termination of GLib main loop based on "quit" flag in C

Tags: c, glib

I realize that this may be a novice GLib question but I've had a hard time finding code examples that solve my problem below. So I'd like your recommendations before I head too far down a wrong path.

My code listens for D-Bus messages.  One D-Bus message is a "Quit" message that is intended to instruct the main loop to shut down.  If there were no other tasks in the main loop, a simple solution could be to instead simply call `g_main_loop_run()` in the code below and have the D-Bus message handling code (not shown here) execute `g_main_loop_quit()` when the "Quit" message is received.

However, I prefer that the decision to quit be made by main loop, which in turn may perform a variety of other tasks in addition to listening for D-Bus messages.  The following code does this as expected after setting up a working D-Bus server:

```
GMainLoop *glib_mainloop = g_main_loop_new( NULL, false );
/* Set up the D-Bus connection to work in the GLib event loop. */
dbus_connection_setup_with_g_main( dbus_connection, NULL );

/* Run the GLib event loop. */
GMainContext *glib_context = g_main_context_default( );
while( quit_indicator == false )
{
    g_main_context_iteration( glib_context, /*allow blocking=*/false );
    /* Do a variety of other tasks. */
}

g_main_loop_quit( glib_mainloop );
```

Note: the above is a bare minimum of code to illustrate my question and I'm aware that the "other tasks" in the main loop may be better handled by threads, `GSource`s, or other means.  For example, there would be obvious busy-waiting or timing issues if the above code were used as is.

My question is: is the above code sample a proper way to accomplish what I want or is there a more "true" GLib way of doing it?

Comment: This seems like if would be a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7):

Your approach is basically correct. A lot of examples say to use `g_main_loop_run()` and `g_main_loop_quit()` to control the main context, but it’s clearer to iterate the main context manually as you are doing.

One change which should be made to your code is to tell `g_main_context_iteration()` to allow blocking, otherwise your main loop is essentially a busy loop, and your process will not sleep while waiting for I/O. You also don’t need to use a `GMainLoop` at all if you iterate the `GMainContext` manually.

Another necessary change is to call `g_main_context_wakeup()` to wake up the main context from blocking in `g_main_context_iteration()` when you change the value of the termination condition.

Thirdly, creating and quitting a `GMainLoop` with `g_main_loop_new()`/`g_main_loop_quit()` does nothing in your code, since that `GMainLoop` is never run with `g_main_loop_run()`. Drop those calls.

Here’s an updated version:

```
GMainContext *context = g_main_context_default ();
gboolean quit = FALSE;

/* Set up the D-Bus connection to work in the GLib event loop. */
dbus_connection_setup_with_g_main (dbus_connection, context);

/* Run the GLib event loop. */
while (!quit)
  g_main_context_iteration (context, TRUE);

/* To exit the main loop (from a callback implementing your D-Bus Quit() function): */
quit = TRUE;
g_main_context_wakeup (NULL  /* global default main context */);
```

A few other points:

- The ‘other tasks’ from your comment should be executed in callbacks from the main context, as you noted.
- Use GDBus rather than dbus-glib (which is deprecated and unmaintained). I’ve written [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751358/how-to-figure-out-which-d-bus-binding-to-use/44696835#44696835) about why, and how to choose a D-Bus binding.
- If you’re going to do this in a new thread (not the main thread), you should use a new `GMainContext` with `g_autoptr(GMainContext) context = g_main_context_new (); g_main_context_push_thread_default (context);`. You should not share a `GMainContext` between multiple threads. While it is safe to do this, it is not performant.

Here’s an MPL-licensed example of the main loop in a modern GLib-based daemon using these techniques: https://git.apertis.org/cgit/rhosydd.git/tree/libcroesor/service.c#n569

Comment: Wonderful! I had certainly missed `g_main_context_wakeup()`. I'm aware that dbus-glib is getting outdated but so far I've been unable to find working examples of GDBus.

Comment: There are a load of GDBus examples in the GIO tests. Some of them are linked to from the documentation, but the others are useful too. Look for ‘example’ in these files: https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gio/tests

Comment: Really, really stop using dbus-glib. It’s unsupported and awkward to integrate with things.

Comment: I eventually migrated to GDBus as you recommended. I had dbus-glib up and running with no problems on the development host but the deployment target device using a slightly different Linux distribution seemed to include a buggy version of dbus-glib. Fortunately, migrating to GDBus took only a few hours beginning with no knowledge about GDBus to having integrated it with the remaining code.

Comment: Glad to hear it!