# Simple C or C++ API for controlling systemd services

Tags: c, linux, service, systemd, dbus

## Goal

I'd like to write C/C++ applications and provide an API for them to communicate directly with `systemd`-managed services. Effectively, I'd like my applications to be able to do the equivalent of `systemctl start service_name@unit_number.service` without using `system()`, `popen()`, or `exec()` calls (**hard requirement**).

---

## Question

Is there a **simple** C/C++ API for communicating with `systemd`, assuming `systemd` version 219 (i.e. CentOS v7.4, **also a hard requirement**)?

---

## Work So Far

1. I've scoured online for examples of controlling `systemd`-managed services in C/C++ and [found the odd discussion on the topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/systemd/comments/61lakf/help_me_get_status_and_start_a_systemd_service/), but haven't found any good examples.
2. I could always reverse-engineer [`systemctl` version 219 from source](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/releases/tag/v219), but then I potentially run afoul of GPL licensing.
3. [Since I'm stuck with CentOS v7.4, which means I can't get at version 221 or later of systemd, I can't use the newer "SD Bus" API.](http://0pointer.net/blog/the-new-sd-bus-api-of-systemd.html) [Nobody would allow manually upgrading `libsystemd` just for an application-specific benefit, and I'm apparently not the first person to raise this concern.](https://lwn.net/Articles/648728/)
4. [I'm hesitant to use the low-level C API for DBUS](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/index.html), since the maintainers themselves state "**If you use this low-level API directly, you're signing up for some pain.**".

---

## Hard Requirements

- `systemd` v219.
- CentOS v7.4
- C/C++.
- No `system()`/`popen()`/`exec()` calls to the `systemctl` CLI utility.
- Non-propagating license (i.e. LGPLv2 is OK, though BSD/MIT is preferred).

---

## Question (Redux)

Is there a simpler API that I could use on CentOS v7.4 (even if I have to supply the shared library myself) that can be used to communicate with `systemd` in a simple, reliable manner directly via C/C++ code? **If the existing `libdbus-1.so` API is complicated but still reliable, and I can create a reliable/stable wrapper library around it, I'm open to exploring that option.** Also, if it's possible to manually build and deploy the SD-BUS components independent of `systemd` and use them without having to modify/upgrade the `systemd` library/daemon already on the system, I could potentially go that route too.

---

## Edits & Comments

- I would be open to using a mature C++ library, so long as it doesn't require total release of all source.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into using a C++ wrapper library?  There are a few that exist already that make the dbus library easier to use.

Comment: @rm5248 I would be open to using a mature C++ library, so long as it doesn't require total release of all source. Thanks!

Comment: Since the systemd API is exposed as a set of D-Bus interfaces, this question essentially boils down to ‘what C/C++ D-Bus bindings do you recommend?’ — which is covered by [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751358/how-to-figure-out-which-d-bus-binding-to-use/44696835#44696835), together with their pros and cons.

Answer (score 3):

As you already figured out, you should only interact with systemd using a dbus library, there is no other supported way to do so.
Even if you lifted the requirement of no execution of binaries, it will remain frowned upon, as the *ctl tools are command line **user interfaces** not intended or designed to be called from other programs.

Comment: You also figured out that this seems to be a common problem and the new "SD Bus" API solves it. Why do you think there is a non-painfull old API when they made a shiny new API to be less painful?

Comment: There is indeed adviced to use sd-bus.. but from C++ pretty much the only mature well tested, well supported choice he has is qtdbus.