# Choosing cross-distro DBus implementation

Tags: linux, dbus, bluez

I'm trying to write a systemd daemon which should register new service in SDP, listen for RFCOMM connections and exchange some information with other Bluetooth devices. The daemon should be as distro-independent as possible. Since I want to use BlueZ5 I need to make use of DBus (which is new to me).

So here comes my question, will choosing GDBus make my daemon run only on systems with GNOME installed? Or similiarly, will QtDBus only work with KDE? If yes, what should I do to be able to run it on multiple distros?

Comment: IMO glib, gio libraries are the minimal dependency in any desktop distributions. So developing Bluetooth applications based on GDbus should not be a problem for any desktop. You can find some examples here : https://gist.github.com/parthitce and details here : https://www.linumiz.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [freedesktop wiki](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/dbus/)

> The low-level libdbus reference library has no required dependencies;
>   the reference bus daemon's only required dependency is an XML parser
>   (expat). Higher-level bindings specific to particular frameworks (Qt,
>   GLib, Java, C#, Python, etc.) add more dependencies, but can make more
>   assumptions and are thus much simpler to use. The bindings evolve
>   separately from the low-level libdbus, so some are more mature and
>   ABI-stable than others; check the docs for the binding you plan to
>   use.

So you can be as platform independent as you want.

Parthiban's suggestion in the comments is probably your best bet, since even the libdbus developers recommend GDBus as the better option.

A nice overview of your options can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44696835/2931197).

Comment: You are correct. But using libdbus means *If you use this low-level API directly, you're signing up for some pain* (copied from https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/)

Comment: Niall’s answer is good. You may find some additional detail on the differences between the different D-Bus client libraries here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44696835/2931197.