# DBUS dbus_pending_call_steal_reply assertion

Tags: embedded-linux, glib, dbus

i am getting an dbus assertion and application crash randomly at the time of DBUS initialisation.

Below is my code code snippet to get dbus.

```
px_sess_ctxt->px_bus = dbus_g_bus_get (DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &ppx_error);
if (NULL == px_sess_ctxt->px_bus)
   {
     return ERROR_1;
   }

   px_bus_proxy = dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name (px_sess_ctxt->px_bus,
                     PROXY_NAME, PROXY_PATH,PROXY_INTERFACE_NAME);
   if (NULL == px_bus_proxy)
   {
      return ERROR_2;
   }
dbus_g_proxy_call (px_bus_proxy, "pingMethod", &ppx_error,
                   G_TYPE_STRING, svc_name,G_TYPE_UINT, 0, G_TYPE_INVALID, G_TYPE_UINT, &ui_ret, G_TYPE_INVALID);
```

Randomly i get segmentation cash followed by dbus_g_proxy_call() fail.
below is the error i get when the proxy call fails.

```
process 1559: arguments to dbus_pending_call_steal_reply() were incorrect, assertion "pending->reply != NULL" failed in file dbus-pending-call.c line 715.
 This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
   D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
```

Please let use know any issue faced in dbus-glib libs. This would be very much helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Does the `pingMethod` method actually return a reply? What does `dbus-monitor` show as the traffic on the bus? What’s the backtrace of the assertion failure? (Run under `gdb`.)

Comment: 1. No tested pingMethod and dbus-monitor. I will test and update.
2. Tried taking core-dump and analysed. last function gdb coredump points is from dbus. after that no stack trace.
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x215082a4 in kill () from /lib/libc.so.0
#1  0x2152e852 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.0
#2  0x2015b646 in ?? () from /lib/libdbus-1.so.3.7.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Answer (score 1):

As you are finding, the dbus-glib client bindings to D-Bus are hard to use. They are deprecated and unmaintained, and it’s highly recommended that you do not use them.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751358/how-to-figure-out-which-d-bus-binding-to-use/44696835#44696835) for discussion of alternative client bindings to use. If you are already using GLib in your project, then [GDBus](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html) (part of GIO, which is part of GLib) is the obvious choice to use.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I am using legacy code and i can not change that (very big code). Please let me know any debugging way's to debug dbus-glib.