# libdbus: get a list of strings from DBusMessage arguments

Tags: c, linux, dbus

I've recently been learning about `libdbus` by writing a simple tool that sends [mpris](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/) messages to active media players.

The first step of this has been fetch a list of media players via DBus:

```
    // send the ListNames command over the DBus
    DBusMessage* msg = dbus_message_new_method_call(
        "org.freedesktop.DBus",
        "/",
        "org.freedesktop.DBus",
        "ListNames");

    // send the message
    DBusPendingCall* call;
    dbus_bool_t success = dbus_connection_send_with_reply(con, msg, &call, 100);
    if (!success || call == NULL) return 1;

    // wait for a reply
    dbus_pending_call_block(call);

    // check reply
    DBusMessage* reply = dbus_pending_call_steal_reply(call);
```

I must now parse the DBus reply for a list of media player names.
After reading the reference material, I believe this should be possible via [dbus_message_get_args](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusMessage.html#gad8953f53ceea7de81cde792e3edd0230), as the documentation notes:

> arrays of string, object path, and signature are supported; but these are returned as allocated memory and must be freed with dbus_free_string_array(). [...] To get a string array pass in "char ***array_location" and "int *n_elements".

This led me to write the following:

```
    // pull list of players from reply
    const int MAX_ARGS = 10;
    const char** args;
    dbus_message_get_args(reply, &err, DBUS_TYPE_ARRAY, &args, &MAX_ARGS);
```

But upon checking my DBusError, I get the following message:

> DBus Error:
> org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs
> Argument 0 is specified to be an array of "unknown", but is actually an array of "string"

I originally assumed I must have been passing a bad `DBUS_TYPE` but couldnt find one more suitable than `DBUS_TYPE_ARRAY`.

I'm aware that this is also possible by using a `dbus_message_iter` call but the documentation seems to suggest this is not necessary, and even suggests using `get_message_args` where possible.

**So the actual question is...** am I missing something about the documentation, or calling the function wrong? Or is getting a list of strings actually not possible with this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading the libdbus source code to be sure, but something like this is my recollection:

```
dbus_message_get_args(reply, &err, DBUS_TYPE_ARRAY,
        DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &args, &len, DBUS_TYPE_INVALID);
```

Note that `len` is not a maximum length you can specify: libdbus will write the actual length of the array there. I'm not 100% sure of the argument order here, you might have to read the source to be sure.

If you are now thinking "but that would be a weird API with bad documentation"... you would be right: As Philip mentioned using libdbus is not a good choice to make in 2020.

Comment: this looks about right, will try it as soon as I get back to work on this and will let you know if it works :D complete tangent: I have to wonder about whether unclear documentation warrants a library being completely abandoned but then I remember that Im also only scratching the surface of this library and there are probably much worse problems haha

Comment: It's not that I want to abandon libdbus, it's more that e.g. GDBus is a much better API with few downsides (basically libdbus is low-level and quite hard to use correctly without offering any major benefits in comparison): so the more reasonable question is 'why would I use an inferior API?'. There could be edge cases where libdbus is a good choice but I've personally not seen any yet. GDBus requires a bit of learning as well but once you figure it out handling complex method/signal signatures becomes so much easier than it is with libdbus

Comment: Just confirmed this fix, works perfectly :) tyvm

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to not use `libdbus-1`, as it’s a very low level D-Bus library — and as you’ve found, it’s hard to use.

Use a higher level D-Bus library like [GDBus](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html) or [QtDBus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html). You will make your life a whole lot easier.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751358/how-to-figure-out-which-d-bus-binding-to-use/44696835#44696835).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, Im aware of all that, but I'm not exactly using this library for any practical reason other than the novelty, so I'd like to continue searching for direct answers to the question